# Should rice cooker bowls be refrigerated?

Tags: rice-cooker

Whenever I can't finish all the rice in the rice cooker bowl, I place the [bowl](https://i5.walmartimages.com/asr/652a2259-f778-4717-9cac-72f7a89e15d6_1.7cefe0f5e84e3d6798152796b3c19c29.jpeg?odnHeight=560&odnWidth=560&odnBg=FFFFFF) (with the lid on) into the refrigerator, to shirk transferring the rice to a container (e.g. [Glasstock](http://glasslockusa.com/product-category/oven-safe/rectangles/)).

Does this refrigeration damage the bowl?

Comment: I do this all the time (cheap rice cooker, cheap rice cooker bowl) with no ill effect.

Answer (score 2):

When I had one it was non stick aluminum which is something I'd happily put in the fridge. This seems to be common. The bowl is oversized for the amount of rice you'd want to chill, so it dries out. Anyway you should cool rice quickly, such as with cold water which would then need draining, at which point you might as well use a smaller container. I wouldn't usually have the fridge space for a rice cooker bowl.

Comment: If there isn't a whole lot in the pot in the first place, you could set the bowl in a larger bowl (or the sink) with ice water ... then you don't need to worry about draining.